# Using bond energies to calculate the released energy of a neutralization reaction

Tags: acid-base, energy

I am trying to make a simulation of a neutralization reaction that simulates the change in enthalpy as the reaction progresses. The strategy I have decided to go with is using the energy of the covalent bonds to find the difference in energy released (bond being formed) and energy consumed (bond breaking) by the system. The system I am working with is

$$\ce{HCl(aq) + NaOH(aq) → NaCl(aq) + H2O(l)}$$

What is giving me trouble is that I can't find a reliable way to do this. The closest have gotten to figuring it out is this [answer](https://socratic.org/questions/why-is-a-neutralization-reaction-exothermic#:%7E:text=In%20a%20neutralization%20raction%2C%20an,that%20gives%20its%20exothermic%20character.), but it does not finish the example in what bonds are being broken/formed and what values I should be using for the bond energies (I have searched up tables of bond energies but I am still a little confused on how to use them in this context). If anyone has a more clean cut explanation and could go more in depth showing how this works It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Be aware that both HCl and NaOH are fully dissociated before neutralization, which is just H+(aq) + OH-(aq) -> H2O(l)

Comment: Quote at least the essential relevant info from referred links for the question making sense for future readers even with  links being broken.

Comment: No bonds are broken when $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$ solutions are mixed, because the only reaction that occurs is  $\ce{H^+ + OH- -> H2O}$. Just one covalent bond is formed between $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{O}$. Covalent bonds $\ce{H-Cl}$ do not exist any more in aqueous $\ce{HCl}$ solutions